# The tag [using] on SO has overloaded meanings

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

On SO, the tag [using](/questions/tagged/using) seems to be used for two different things:

1. Discussing the `using` keyword in C# and a few other related issues
2. Not knowing what the tag field is for; e.g. questions "tagged" [[validation] [using] [struts2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339799/disabling-the-validation-in-struts2-and-use-my-own-customized-validation), or [[printing] [list] [using] [haskell]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850748/printing-list-of-strings-using-unwords-in-haskell).

The second use of [using](/questions/tagged/using) seems to be less than useful. Should I go in and remove the offending tag in case 2, or am I nitpicking?

Comment: Yes, you should.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Should I go in and remove the offending tag in case 2

Yes, please!

> am I nitpicking?

Nits are annoying, nasty creatures that are to be dealt with harshly.  So yes, and it's a good thing.

Answer (score 6):

Anytime you see that the OP doesn't understand tags (random sentence entered as tags), then please fix it.

The help about tags talks about "Combine multiple words into single-words", but there are clearly some non English-speakers who don't know what that means.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should, and while you are at it, if you had the rep, put the text into shape.