# The tag [stackoverflow] has multiple definitions

Tags: discussion, tags, ambiguous-tags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450686/xsl-processor-stack-has-overflowed-cant-understand-why) is using [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) in the programming sense, while [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436528/how-are-the-new-answer-notifications-implemented-in-stackoverflow-com), also tagged [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow), is asking about the way a feature on stackoverflow.com is implemented.

I suggest creating a new tag, [stackoverflow.com](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow.com), for questions about how things on our favorite website are implemented and leaving [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) for people who have problems with memory management.

It appears [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6928/how-to-handle-tags-with-multiple-meanings) addresses what I am asking for, but has no definitive answer other than "fix it yourself."

Comment: or fixed even more succinctly, [stackoverflow] for the website, and [stack-overflow] for the memory error.

Comment: I think that leads to more confusion.  As a newcomer how would I differentiate between [stackoverflow] and [stack-overflow]? Choosing [stack-overflow] and [stackoverflow.com] as per your original suggestion offers much more clarity.

Comment: I [just posted this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60350/remove-tag-synonym-stack-overflow-stackoverflow), before I saw your question, but I believe we're proposing different solutions to similar problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are approaching this the wrong way: new users will always use the `stackoverflow` tag to refer to either the website or the error, so no matter what you do that tag is doomed.

I have a better idea: rename the website to http://www.wafflesoverflow.com; this will solve the tag problem. The domain is not currently registered.

Comment: That was what i was thinking, the name of the website is the redefinition

Answer (score 0):

i think that the best, most clear way to set it up for newcomers and old is to roll all stackoverflow the website tagged questions into a tag [stackoverflow.com] and roll all stackoverflow the exception into [stackoverflow] and [stack-overflow]

Comment: That won't happen if you're doing an actual tag search.

Comment: i have to bracket? i guess that makes sense.  My bad.

Comment: The tag wiki now agrees with you, but it hasn't stopped people from using `[stackoverflow]` for both meanings.