# Ambiguous tag: ming

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, ambiguous-tags

The [ming](/questions/tagged/ming) tag is being used for both:

- a php library for creating flash swf content
- an object document mapper for mongodb.

The php library has a about 6 questions with the tag and the mongodb has 4.

I've looked at [How to handle tags with multiple meanings?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6928/how-to-handle-tags-with-multiple-meanings) but 
its not clear to me what these should be retagged to.

Would [mongodb-ming](/questions/tagged/mongodb-ming) and [php-ming](/questions/tagged/php-ming) be suitable?

Comment: There are four questions tagged ming.  All of them also have the mongodb tag.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Robert: Me being slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and retagged all the ones relating to PHP to [libming](/questions/tagged/libming) because apparently the [Ming Library](http://www.libming.org) is actually available for other platforms aside from PHP.

> Ming is a library for generating Macromedia Flash files (.swf), written in C, and includes useful utilities for working with .swf files.
>
> It has wrappers that allow it to be used in C++, PHP, Python, Ruby, and Perl.

So, it just happens to have only been used so far by PHP questions here.

Comment: I added a [ming-library] synonym.  libming is not very discoverable, and nobody thought to call it that.

Comment: @Robert: What makes this undiscoverable is the fact that typing "ming" into the tags box brings up all the " program **ming** " tags, rather than something actually related...

Comment: @animuson Thanks, I've added a tag wiki entry for libming now.