# Improve visibility of related/alternate tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

> Originated from [links to related tags](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/links-to-related-tags)
>
> May be helpful: [A real solution to ambiguous tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags)

It would be pretty nice to have a sort of 'tag suggestions' feature. Sort of like the Gmail labs feature "Don't forget Bob!".

Normally, when tagging stuff, most of the time you don't even know if a tag exists. Typing segments of various related topics and waiting for a tag to appear is annoying. You don't want to create a bunch of tags either.

So basically I propose that the system should look for tags which are often used in conjunction with the tags which hav already been entered, as well as look for commonly used tags in the "related questions" titlebox dropdown.

Possibly we could also have a way for users to enter related tags (a section of the tagwiki perhaps), that the system could utilise for this feature.

Answer (score 5):

I was actually going to suggest something like this myself in relation to [this recent question about the [ming] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126066/ambiguous-tag-ming/126068#126068). When I type the word "ming" into the tags box, it looks like this:

[image: Comic Part #0001]

Obviously, someone searching for Ming-related tags is not going to be helped very much by this word. It brings up *just* the [ming](/questions/tagged/ming) tag, and not the more relevant [libming](/questions/tagged/libming) tag, which may be what they're actually looking for.

A good fix to this would be to allow tags to specify **possible alternatives**. Going off the premise of making tag wikis describe the proper use of the tag, they should be smart enough to pick up on tags used within the tag wiki context, and display those tags before the other "matches" in the menu.

For example, if I added this line to the Ming tag wiki:

> Not to be used for the Ming Library for SWF creation, see [libming](/questions/tagged/libming).

Then why not use that tag?

[image: Comic Part #0002]

Of course, if you wanted to be more elegant, you could always add a separate section to specify alternative tags. This is just one way of doing it.

[image: Comic Part #0003]

<sub>**Note:** No joke intended by the use of "iPhone" being kind to another service.</sub>