# Tag suggestions in the right sidebar?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Improve visibility of related/alternate tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126092/improve-visibility-of-related-alternate-tags)

If a user adds e.g. the tags html, javascript and css to his favorite tags in the right sidebar there could be a small area called "suggested tags" above the favorite tags that informs him of tags that are often used in combination with the other tags he already added, e.g. ajax or jquery.

And yes I know that I can click on a tag an see related tags on the right top. this idea is more of a merger/short overview  of all tags used/of interest for a user.

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/links-to-related-tags http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126092/improve-visibility-of-related-alternate-tags (possible dupe of last one)