# Partition tag is ambiguous

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, ambiguous-tags

As I've been cleaning up the tags on questions I've answered I've found several that have multiple meanings.  Per @PopularDemand's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6928/how-to-handle-tags-with-multiple-meanings), I'll post a question about the [partition](/questions/tagged/partition) tag as a test case for me about how to handle ambiguous tags.

The partition tag has been used on questions that

- Discuss disk partition issues
- Data base partition issues
- Hadoop partitioning isues
- Various splitting of data collections into smaller data collection issues

Each of these topics has its own set of subject matter experts, fun facts to know and tell and audiences.  The [Partition] tag isn't really very useful as a filter since each of these topics has a good number of questions.

I think we need:

- A [disk-partition] tag,
- A [hadoop-partitioning] tag and
- A [data-partitioning] tag.

There already is a [database-partition] tag.

Comment: I've created all the tags you recommended and started to retag some questions.  Pay attention to the `disk-partitioning` tag, as it has a good chance of being off-topic.

Comment: Is the goal to eventually change the [partition] tag's wiki to say don't use this or to eventually delete the [partition] tag?

Comment: To delete the [partition] tag.  If it's ambiguous, then it's not a very good tag to begin with and should probably have a better, more specific tag.  If you change the tag wiki to say "don't use this", then you might as well do the work to remove the tag.  No use in doing just 1/2 the job.

Comment: OK... with the exception of this question: http://superuser.com/questions/469376/corrupted-winxp-partition (which was just migrated to SuperUser which has no [disk-partition] tag) all uses of the [partition] tag have been retagged.  Wiki changes have been made to the original [partition] tag and the three tags created by @casperOne.

Comment: No need to make changing to the partition tag wiki.  I've retagged the migrated question on this side (which doesn't affect the other side), so `partition` will be gone soon.  No need for the tag wiki.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note, there's also the `partitions` tag with 47 questions.

Comment: Done with `partitions`.  There's still `partitioning`.  Unngh.