# 'brackets' vs. 'adobe-brackets' tag

Tags: discussion, ambiguous-tags

(Going based on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107758/208011) suggesting separate threads per instance of ambiguous/multiple-meaning tags).

Questions related to the [Brackets code editor](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/) seem to use one of two different tags: [brackets](/questions/tagged/brackets) or [adobe-brackets](/questions/tagged/adobe-brackets).  The "brackets" tag's description is all about Brackets, the editor, but most questions tagged [brackets](/questions/tagged/brackets) are actually about the programming punctuation character.  So "adobe-brackets" seems like a more correct choice -- except that the maintainers [usually ask people to omit "Adobe" from the name](https://twitter.com/brackets/status/278993658609553409).

Here's my proposal:

- Rename [adobe-brackets](/questions/tagged/adobe-brackets) to [brackets-editor](/questions/tagged/brackets-editor) (is tag renaming possible?)
- For anything tagged [brackets](/questions/tagged/brackets) that's actually about Brackets, remove that tag and replace with [brackets-editor](/questions/tagged/brackets-editor)
- Change the description of [brackets](/questions/tagged/brackets) to refer to the programming punctuation

So, my questions:

1. Is that the best way to clean this up?
2. Being relatively new here... how would I go about doing so?  Do I just make a series of proposed edits and hope they're all consistently approved by the peer reviewers?

Comment: > Rename adobe-brackets to brackets-editor

sounds good